# jQuery fade replace two images on hover

Tags: jquery, replace, hover, fade

I have problem with my script.

I have object with id "web_click" and image with id "web". I want to make that when I hover (or mouseover) "web_click" in image "web" source will be replace from 'web.png' to 'web_hover.png' (these image have the same dimensions) with fade effect. Of course on 'mouseout' or finish hover source must replace to non-hover image with fade also.

But now this script make fadeIn on hover to 'web_hover.png' and disappering (both images are not display) and when I move out cursor from "web_click" image come back to 'web.png' with fade effect. Why it hiding when I hover?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#web_click").hover(function() {
$('#web').fadeOut();
    $("#web").attr ("src","png/two/web_hover.png");
        }, function() {
            $('#web').fadeIn();
    $("#web").attr ("src","png/two/web.png");
});

});
```

update: I made this method and fade works but is delay between images. First image fade out, here is little pause and both images are not display, and second image fade in. How can I make this without this break between these?

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#web_click").mouseover(function() {
        $("#web").fadeOut('100', function(){
            $("#web").attr ("src","png/two/web_hover.png"); 
            $('#web').fadeIn('100');    
    });
    });
$("#web_click").mouseout(function() {
    $("#web").fadeOut('100', function(){
        $("#web").attr ("src","png/two/web.png");
        $('#web').fadeIn('100');
    });
});
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    <style type="text/css">
        img
        {
            position:absolute;
        }
    </style>
    <div id="web_click">
        <img src="png/two/web_hover.png" alt="Alternate Text" />
        <img style="display:none" src="png/two/web.png" alt="Alternate Text" />
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $("#web_click").hover(function () {
            $('#web_click img').fadeToggle()
        }, function () {
            $('#web_click img').fadeToggle()
        });
    </script>
```

The style for img is used to place the two image in same place

Comment: Thank you for reply but I can't use it. web_click is a href image to change two pngs on hover. web.png have additionally parameters to the parallax script but position of img must be in css. I made also this:
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#web_click").mouseover(function() {
$('#web').fadeIn("slow");
$("#web").attr ("src","png/two/web_hover.png"); 
});
$("#web_click").mouseout(function() {
$('#web').fadeIn("slow");
$("#web").attr ("src","png/two/web.png"); 
});
});
</script>
replace image on mouseover and mousout works but fade doesn't appear. May you know what I should fix in this?

Comment: The codes I written here is just a example, you can change it to whatever you want. But make sure that you must place two images in the same position. You can remove one and change the src after the fade.